# How to skip initial Apollo query and fetch data on button click?

Tags: redux, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I have a container in my React / Redux app with multiple mutations and a query:

```
const MenuWithData = compose(
    graphql(GET_FINAL_CODE_BY_PROJECT_ID, {
        options: ownProps => ({
            variables: {
                id: ownProps.projectId,
            },
            skip: true,
        }),
        props: ({ data }) => data,
    }),
    graphql(DELETE_PROJECT, {
        props: ({ ownProps, mutate }) => ({
            async deleteProject() {
                // ...
            },
        }),
    }),
)(Menu);

export default connect(
    state: ({
        projectId: state.current.projectId,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
        deleteProject(id) {
            dispatch(deleteProject(id));
        },
    })
)(MenuWithData);
```

The container sends the `deleteProject` function through the props to the `<Menu>` component and I call it when a user clicks on the "Delete" button.

I'm trying to do the same thing with the query, but I can't seem to find a way to send it to the component. If I use `skip: true`, I don't have access to the `refetch` method, but if I set it to `false`, then the query executes on load.

Is there a way to execute Apollo queries on events that happen in the component?

Answer (score 2):

You should utilize the `withApollo` HOC instead of `graphql`:

```
const MenuWithData = compose(
    withApollo,
    graphql(DELETE_PROJECT, {
        props: ({ ownProps, mutate }) => ({
            async deleteProject() {
                // ...
            },
        }),
    }),
)(Menu);
```

This will pass your client instance down to the component, so you can do something like this inside your button's click handler:

```
props.client.query({
  query: GET_FINAL_CODE_BY_PROJECT_ID,
  variables: { id: props.projectId },
}).then(({ data, errors }) => {
  // handle result
})
```

FWIW, the convention is to never have queries mutate anything -- if calling a query is going to change data, it should be a mutation. Apollo is built around this idea, with the drastically different way queries and mutations are handled by the same HOC.

If you're not firing the query until a user does something, it sounds like your query is potentially mutating data, in which case it may be worth considering making it a mutation in the first place.

Comment: I have a list of projects on a page that have been loaded with incomplete data. Not everybody needs the final code, so that's the reason it's being queried on demand. I ended up doing something similar, but inside the container, not the component: http://snippi.com/s/22b25fw - I'm trying to keep Apollo and Redux logic out of my components. Does it look weird?

Comment: It's a little unconventional to utilize connect like that if you're not going to fire an action with that handler. A cleaner approach might be to utilize something like `recompose`'s `withHandlers` HOC. Also, FWIW, you can just lump all your HOCs under the compose, like this: http://snippi.com/s/0ktv5xd